# DateTime ParseExact method "\" at beginning of string

Tags: c#, datetime

I am using

```
DateTime day = DateTime.ParseExact(d, "M/d/yyyy",
System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

and it is throwing a "String not recognized as a valid DateTime" FormatException

I've looked through all the other questions dealing with ParseExact and have not been able to figure out where my discrepancy is...

I noticed that the string d has a "\" before it, and ends with an extra "
See below :
[image]

I am not sure where those extra characters are coming from but am pretty sure they something to do with the parse exact fail.

Comment: Knowing how to read the debugger output is kinda important.  Practice using the text visualizer, spy glass icon in the quick watch window.  Now you see that the string contains extra double quotes.  The TextFieldParser class tends to be the correct solution, depends where it came from.  We can't tell, not a good snippet.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are no slashes.  Those are escapes for the double quotes.

```
var day = DateTime.ParseExact(d.Trim('"'), "M/d/yyyy",
                              CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

Answer (score 1):

It seems like you need to `unescape` the string.

Sample:

```
var d = "\"8/1/2016\"";
var escapedString = d.Replace(@"""", string.Empty);
DateTime day = DateTime.ParseExact(escapedString, @"M/d/yyyy", System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

Answer (score 0):

I used

```
d = d.Substring(1, d.Length - 2);
```

to get rid of the leading and trailing 
 \" from my string.

After that the function worked fine. Still not sure where the \" was coming from at this time.

Comment: Look at how `d` got initialized and work backwards to figure out where the extra double quotes came from.